# Review queue page doesn't fit into screen horizontally

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, review, ios

I'm using mobile Chrome (Firefox and Safari also affected) on iOS 11 on iPad Pro 10.5". Any page for empty review queue, e.g. [Close Votes queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/close) doesn't fit into screen horizontally:

> [image: does not fit]

Page that contains a [list of all review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review) fits fully in horizontal:

> [image: fit normally]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, probably as part of the [Visual design changes to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360198/295232)

[image]

<sub>not marking this as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), that's something we usually leave to staff</sub>