# Top bar buttons are broken when page is zoomed or shifted

Tags: bug, top-bar, zoom

I know that SE only supports 100% scale factor (and doesn’t support mobile browsers in full web at all) on their sites. But before today top bar worked well even after zooming on my iPad. Here is the video:

> [image: video]

Looks like the button tap positions are wrongly shifted while page is zoomed. This is probably happened after the “help” button returning to the top bar.

Shifting the page also leads to the same behavior. E.g. empty review queue page [may not fit into screen horizontally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302561/339911) and can be shifted to the left (when top bar is sticky, like on SO) on the my device, i.e. no zoom here:

> [image: shifted]

For me at least two sites are affected: SO in English and SO in Russian.

I use iPad Pro 10.5 iOS 11.2.1 Google Chrome.

Comment: If its not supported, don't zoom the page?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek in some cases zooming is necessary, e.g. easy to tap big button than small one. Also as I said, that this worked fine before and works on MSE for example, i.e. can be easily fixed.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek on a phone it's pretty hard to use the site *without* zooming.  While there are mobile versions of the Q&A sites, there's no mobile version of the network site itself, and I use that all the time on my phone to view rep changes.  Which I can't do without zooming, both for legibility and hitting the right button on a tiny screen.

Comment: For what it's worth, no repro on stackexchange.com on my Android phone (in Chrome).  You said it works on MSE for you, so it sounds like it's specific to the SO design?

Comment: @MonicaCellio probably yes. All SO sites (En, Pt, Ru, Es, Ja) are affected.

Comment: I use SU as desktop by preference on a 1080p phone.