# Page scale changed while entering tag name on iPad

Tags: bug, tags, design, ios

Entering a tag name can change the page scale on iPad. For instance, normal scale yet:

> [image: normal]

Scale is changed after adding “w” letter:

> [image: scaled]

This’s happening due to changing the page (search results) content. Related bug report: [Review queue page doesn't fit into screen horizontally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302561/339911)